# Graceful shutdowns on Cloud Run

Tags: go, google-cloud-run, sigterm

I'm referring to this article: [Graceful Shutdowns on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive)

The example outlines how to do this in Node.js.

How would one do this in Golang?  Any issues with simply adding this to the `func init()` method?

```golang
func shutdownGracefully() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-c
        // Do some cleanup stuff here...

        os.Exit(0)
    }()
}
```

Comment: That should work, have you tried trying it?

Comment: yes, it seems to work, just wanted to check if that there are no side-effects relating to Cloud Run instance terminations - i.e. could a 'background' goroutine stop an instance from terminating or are termination purely driven by received requests?

Comment: The first paragraph of the page you linked seems pretty clear. If the container does not exit, it will be terminated after 10 seconds. There's no such thing as a "background goroutine"; all goroutines are equal, and when `main()` returns, the program exits and all its goroutines end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have sample Go code for proper signal handling at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/pull/1902. It's not merged yet but essentially highlights how to do this properly on Go.

Beware that when running locally, sending Ctrl+C to your application is a SIGINT, however on Cloud Run you will be getting SIGTERM. It is also important to pass cancellations properly and handling server shutdown gracefully while not dropping the ongoing requests (though, `net/http.Server` handles a decent portion of this for you as you’ll see in sample code).

Answer (score 0):

> How would one do this in Golang?

An idiomatic way to handle graceful shutdowns in go is having a `select` statement  blocking the main goroutine listening for any signal. From there you can trigger all the proper shutdowns when necessary.

For instance:

```
select {
case err := <-anyOtherError:
    // ...
case signal := <- c:
    // Handle shutdown e.g. like http Server Shutdown
}
```

I like to set it inside a `run` function with other startup tasks like starting the server, configs, etc.